# Distance between mid point of two sides of a quadrilateral

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, quadrilateral, geometric-inequalities

Given any quadrilateral ABCD. Let X be the midpoint of side AB and Y be the midpoint of side CD. How can I prove that **XY is not greater than max{AC, BD}** ? Intuitively I see it is true in all cases, but don't have a clue how to prove this.

[image]

I started using the argument that XY <= AD, considering AD be the longest diagonal. This gives me two triangles ACD and ADB. Not sure whether that will help eventually or not. –

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I started using the argument that XY <= AD, considering AD be the longest diagonal. This gives me two triangles ACD and ADB. Not sure whether that will help eventually or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$XY=|\vec{XY}|=\left|\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{AC}+\vec{BD}\right)\right|\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(|\vec{AC}|+|\vec{BD}|\right)\leq\max\{AC,BD\}.$$

I used the following reasoning.
$$\vec{XY}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{XA}+\vec{AC}+\vec{CY}+\vec{XB}+\vec{BD}+\vec{DY}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{XA}+\vec{XB}+\vec{CY}+\vec{DY}+\vec{AC}+\vec{BD}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{0}+\vec{0}+\vec{AC}+\vec{BD}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{AC}+\vec{BD}\right).$$

Comment: How did you come up with $|XY| = |\frac{1}{2}(AC+BD)|$? I did not understand that part.

Comment: @Mateo I added something. See now.

Comment: I understand now. You used the polygon law of vector addition. The proof looks good. I am trying to prove the same argument using triangle inequality. I will post the solution if I become successful.

Comment: @Mateo I can prove it by the triangle inequality, but it's a very ugly here.